# select orderby_sort option for sorting by store price

Tags: expresso-store, low-search

This sorts the items correctly but I am failing to pre-select the option they selected using a conditional.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<select name="orderby_sort">
    <option value="">Sort by</option>
    <option value="store:price|asc"{if low_search_store:orderby_sort == "store:price|asc"} selected{/if}>Price (low-high)</option>
    <option value="store:price|desc"{if low_search_store:orderby_sort == "store:price|desc"} selected{/if}>Price (high-low)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [rule](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters#params) is `name="foo" value="bar"` => `{low_search_foo} // bar`.

So try `{if low_search_orderby_sort == "store:price|asc"}`.